# force bullet level in restructuredtext

Tags: markup, restructuredtext, docutils

Is there a way to force a particular bullet point level in restructured text?

I have several bulleted lists in containers, eg.

```
.. container::

    + outer entery 1
        - inner entry 1.1
        - inner entry 1.2
        -  ...
```

each such container is followed by several paragraphs of text.

My issue is that, for one such container, I want to "break" it up with text after each bullet point, so I'd have something like

```
.. container::

    + outer entery N

< free text>

.. container::

        - inner entry N.1

< more free text>

.. container::

        - inner entry 1.2

< even more free text>
```

This sort-of works, but the problem is that the inner entries in this case are indented and styled the same as the outer entry (since they are no longer part of a nested bullet list). Is there a way to get them to render at the same level as inner entries in previous containers (e.g. by forcing restructuredtext to read bullet symbols in a analogous way to how it handles section titles)?

Comment: The first example fails to create the inner bullet list. There must be an empty line before the nested list and the indentation must match the start column of the first item content (`outer entry 1`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "skip" the first level of a hierarchical list because "list levels" are derived from the nesting level in Docutils as well as in HTML and LaTeX.

Actually, the internal document tree stores the bullet character as ["bullet" attribute](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#bullet), so a custom writer or an extension could be conceived. However, the problem of representing "topless lists" in HTML remains.